# How to test autorenewal subscriptions on Android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, billing, android-billing

I would like to add a autorenewal subscriptions to my Android app. All code is implemented and passed basic tests, but there is one important use case - I need to ensure, that renewal process (monthly payment) works fine. My server side is responsible for checking of purchase status using Google APIs and I don`t want to wait 1 months in order to check how it works in different cases.

Apple provides a sandbox, where I can configure subscription (its possible to have subscription for 1 minutes and so on). 
Does Google provides something similar (sandbox, test API, etc.) that might help to verify described case?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: possible duplicate of [Testing IAP/In-App Purchase Subscriptions with Google Play/Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861718/testing-iap-in-app-purchase-subscriptions-with-google-play-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Current answer - there is no way to do it. Sad, but truth.

Comment: This is outdated answer now. It's possible to test it just fine.

Comment: can you please tell me the way to test it.

Answer (score 2):

Google Play has already implemented a sandbox to test subscriptions and issue purchases. You need to publish your app in beta and after a few hours of doing that the test users(added in Google Play dev console) can make test purchases(these are not charged) in your app. They can even make subscription test purchases. A test subscription automatically renews every day(until canceled from Google Play) irrespective of the subscription duration.

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html

Also see this: [Testing Android IAP/In-App Purchase Subscriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861718/testing-iap-in-app-purchase-subscriptions-with-google-play-android/28872785#28872785)

Comment: A question: When a test subscription gets auto renewed, I see that the purchase token changes, making impossible for my server side application to check the subscription status. Does anybody have this same problem?