# getPurchases() for renewal subscription returns first purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I need check that user has active subscription after automatic renew.

I do call **getPurchases()** and expect get all subscriptions (expired and active) or at least information about latest automatic purchase. I need datetime and orderID for this renewal for submit to server.

But now **getPurchases()** returns first purchase/subscription only. 
I'm using test subscription with daily renewal (see [Testing Android IAP/In-App Purchase Subscriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861718/testing-iap-in-app-purchase-subscriptions-with-google-play-android/28872785#28872785))

Comment: Hi, did you manage to find a fix? Is this only valid for testing subscriptions?